# Define Directives

Tags: c, output

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("%d",a);
#define a 10
}
```

/* preprocessor activities are done before the compliation takes place ,so why the error is coming in this program,'a' is undefined that is 
a is not defined */

```
/*second doubt*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void fun();

int main()
{
fun();
#define a 20
}

void fun()
{
printf("i m inside the function %d",a);
}

output->i m inside the function 20
```

/* now here also error should come as a is not defined because fun is called before #              define but it works perfectly right */

/*any help will be greatly acknowledged */
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sxhs2ty.aspx),

> Preprocessor directives can appear anywhere in a source file, but they apply only to the remainder of the source file.

In your first example, `a` is used before you `#define` it, whereas in the second, you call `fun` first, but define it later in the source after you have used `#define`. I believe that is why the first one has an error but the second doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor executes uses `#define`s to do search-and-replace *before compile time*. Because of this, using `#define` macros is **not** like declaring variables.

When the preprocessor (separate from the compiler) goes through your code, first it sees the `#define` statement. It interprets this as "Whenever I see `a`, I'm gonna replace it with `20`." Then, after a few more lines, it sees the `a` and replaces it. After this, the compiler runs, and it sees and the following statement:

```
printf("i m inside the function %d",20);
```

20 is a perfectly valid thing to use in this case, so it compiles it accordingly.

Your confusion is due to the order that functions are called in. However, the preprocessor couldn't care less about what calls what. All it cares about is **the order that things appear in the source file**.

Answer (score 0):

Move the #define to after the print statement in your function and then you'll see why this didn't give you an error (and why you now have an error). #defines are only processed for the remainder of the file when they occur. Which is why you generally want to place them at the top of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Like what you said:

> preprocessor activities are done before the compliation takes place

So it should be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define a 10

int main()
{
   printf("%d",a);
}
```

or

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define a 20

void fun();

int main()
{
  fun();
}

void fun()
{
  printf("i m inside the function %d",a);
}
```

If you want to use it inside a function block, change *#define a 10* to *int a = 10;*